# checkbox.attr("checked) as if sentence clause

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I want to use as an if clause for my jQuery program, but can't seem to get the if sentence right (I want something to happen if the box is checked). That means, I don't want something to happen WHEN the box is checked, I want it to happens as part of the function if the box is checked when the function is called. I've set up a fiddle below to illustrate what's going on. This will return the same ("I don't want to see previous picks!) whether or not the #prePick checkbox is checked or not, and I have no idea why.

```js
function checkPick() {
if($('#prePick').prop('checked')) {
        console.log("I want to see the previous picks!");
    }
  else {
    console.log("I don't want to see previous picks!");
    }
  };

checkPick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
            <input type='checkbox' name='prePick'> Show Logged Picks
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to your input since you are using a selector by id "#prePick"

```
<input type='checkbox' id='prePick' name='prePick'>
```

Comment: ugh, put in name and forgot about the id. Can't believe it was this simple and I didn't see it for 2 days. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't want just to check the property, you want to respond to a checked event. That's why you need to bind to a checkbox event:

```
$("#prePic").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        console.log("I want to see the previous picks!");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Satpal So how would I implement this in another function? For instance I have this code I wanted to implement this in `function loadCards() {    
    //writes pick onto cards, makes them visible
    for(x=0;x<currentCards;x++) {
        $(".card").eq(x).attr('src', cards[pick][x]);
        $(".card").eq(x).css('display', 'inline');
        if ($('#prePick').attr('checked')) {
        $(".card").eq(picks[pick]).addClass('historyPick');
        $('.card').eq(picks[pick]).css('border', '4px solid lime');
    }
    }
};`

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič, How you want to use your function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prop function or is function as per Jquery standard way.
WORKING EXAMPLE : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/61acoyq5/)
SAMPLE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>prop demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label for="check1">Check me</label>
<p></p>

<script>
$( "input" ).change(function() {
  var $input = $( this );
  $( "p" ).html(
    ".attr( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.attr( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
    ".prop( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.prop( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
    ".is( \":checked\" ): <b>" + $input.is( ":checked" ) ) + "</b>";
}).change();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I think I finally understand your question :)
You don't care to handle the checked event of a checkbox. You simply want to do something if the checkbox is checked :)

Well, you don't use `attr` for that, you need to use `prop`, like so:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked')
```

Comment: yes exactly, but for some reason `if ($('#prePick').prop('checked')) {` doesn't work